# how to install older version of subversion in Linux Mint

Tags: debian, linux-mint, package-management, subversion

With Linux Mint, when I install `subversion` the `.svn` metadata folders are not compatible with `1.6.18` of Eclipse subversion plugin (`subclipse`). I assume the plugin can only process 1.6 compliant metadata. I want to downgrade to 1.6 version of subversion so that it would be compatible with my Eclipse subclipse plugin as well.

```
$  apt-show-versions -a subversion
subversion deinstall ok config-files
subversion 1.7.5-1ubuntu2 quantal archive.ubuntu.com
subversion not installed
```

The Mint package search does not yield any result for subversion package.
http://packages.linuxmint.com/index.php

Answer (score 1):

Why not upgrade your [`subclipse` plugin](http://subclipse.tigris.org/).
`Subclipse` v1.8.x support `Subversion` v1.7.

Maybe `subversion` 1.7 fix some security issues (don't know if it's true, but nevermind). You should always keep your softwares up to date if you can (and here you can). It's one of the main purpose of `Apt` or any package management system.

Eclipse link : http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x

Comment: thanks and it works. i have also installed svnkit client adapter and svnkit library from subclipse update site.

Comment: after some use, I find that subclipse does not recognize some changes done by subversion client. for example, after i commit recent changes from subversion command line client, it still shows that there are changes to be committed from eclipse. I have refreshed the project a few times, but it still shows that there are changes to be committed when there are none. But if I delete the project from eclipse workspace and reimport again, it now correctly recognizes that there are no changes to commit.

Comment: i don;t know why you couldn't just answer the question. i came here expecting an answer and got "try this instead"